# Form stops to pass data after user has logged in

Tags: php, sorting, select, authentication

I want to sort the items on the page and for that I am using this form:

```
<form method="get" action="">
            <label for="sort">Sort items by</label>
            <select id="sort" name="sort">
                <option value="">-</option>
                <option value="plth">Price (Low to high)</option>
                <option value="phtl">Price (High to low)</option>
                <option value="naz">Name (A-Z)</option>
                <option value="nza">Name (Z-A)</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="sortSubmit" value="GO >">
        </form>
```

After the form has been processed, I will use some sql statements to retrieve the items in desired order from database:

```
if(isset($_GET["sortSubmit"]) && $_GET["sort"] == "plth") {
                    $retrieve = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID <= '9' ORDER BY PRICE ASC";
                }
                elseif (isset($_GET["sortSubmit"]) && $_GET["sort"] == "phtl") {
                    $retrieve = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID <= '9' ORDER BY PRICE DESC";
                }
                elseif (isset($_GET["sortSubmit"]) && $_GET["sort"] == "naz") {
                    $retrieve = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID <= '9' ORDER BY NAME ASC";
                }
                elseif (isset($_GET["sortSubmit"]) && $_GET["sort"] == "nza") {
                    $retrieve = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID <= '9' ORDER BY NAME DESC";
                }
```

The problem is, everything is working fine until a user logs in. After the user has logged in, it stops working completely and I cannot figure out why. With some testing echo statements I found out the form is not passing any data anymore. I cant imagine how this has to do something with sessions or cookies.
Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the idea, but isn't it simply if you set the form action to the index.php and by the logic of index.php to find if you choice the sort action and then generate again the page in required order?

Comment: Instead of using `<a href...`, insert a submit button (`<input type="submit" value="GO" />`) and a hidden action tag (`<input type="hidden" name="action" value="sort" />`). In your PHP code, line 1, change `sortSubmit` to `action` and add the condition `&& $_GET['action'] == 'sort'` to the first `if` clause.

Comment: Look on my answer, may be it will make clear what I have in mind

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="get" action="">
     <label for="sort">Sort items by</label>
     <select id="sort" name="sort">
         <option value="">-</option>
         <option value="plth">Price (Low to high)</option>
         <option value="phtl">Price (High to low)</option>
         <option value="naz">Name (A-Z)</option>
         <option value="nza">Name (Z-A)</option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" value="go">
    </form>
```

Now if this page is called sort.php te form will submit to sort.php too.

This way, in the header you can read values like this.

```
$sort = $_GET['sort'];
switch ($sort){
case "plth": 
$retrieve = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID <= '9' ORDER BY PRICE ASC";
break;
// Other possible value andling here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ...
 The ordered data
 ...
 <form method="get" action="index.php">
    <input type hidden name="manager_action" value="sort">
             <label for="sort">Sort items by</label>
             <select id="sort" name="sort">
                 <option value="">-</option>
                 <option value="plth">Price (Low to high)</option>
                 <option value="phtl">Price (High to low)</option>
                 <option value="naz">Name (A-Z)</option>
                 <option value="nza">Name (Z-A)</option>
             </select>
 </form> 

 <?php // index.php
 ...
 if($_POST['manager_action']=='sort'){
    // regenerate data in right ordered
    // and again generate the html page
 }
 ...

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <label for="sort">Sort items by</label>
    <select id="sort" name="sort">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="plth">Price (Low to high)</option>
        <option value="phtl">Price (High to low)</option>
        <option value="naz">Name (A-Z)</option>
        <option value="nza">Name (Z-A)</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="sortSubmit" value="go">
</form>
```

Note the  was swapped out for . This will submit the form and tell it to add www.yourwebsite.com?sort=nza (for example)

Then in your PHP you can right your if/else's or create a switch statement. I'll use a switch statement because it's a bit quicker than a bunch of if/else's.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET["sortSubmit"])) { // Ask whether the form was submitted or not. Not technically required though. 
        switch($_GET["sort"]) {
            case "plth":
                $retrieve = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID <= '9' ORDER BY PRICE ASC";
                break; 
            case "phtl":
                $retrieve = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID <= '9' ORDER BY PRICE DESC";
                break; 
            case "naz":
                $retrieve = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID <= '9' ORDER BY NAME ASC";
                break; 
            case "nza":
                $retrieve = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID <= '9' ORDER BY NAME DESC";
                break; 
            default: 
                 // Catch anything else
                 break;
        }
    }
?>
```